# FirebaseUI convert anonymous account to permanent account

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using Firebase UI for Android app.  I want users to be able to log in Anonymously and use basic features. Then when they want additional features I want to convert their account to a permanent email/password or google provider account.

Firebase has documentation on a way to do this here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth  by using linkWithCredential

However, I want to do this using Firebase UI auth. 
Is it possible to use this linkWithCredential with FirebaseUI? If so a simple example would be great.

Comment: That's an open feature request on FirebaseUI as far as I know. See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/123

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  Yeah, that looks right.  But that request has been open over a year, do you know of any work around?  I guess we will have to copy the anonymous user data to new account or not use firebase ui.